# async stream `hyper::body::Body` to file in rust

Tags: rust, async-await, hyper

How can you stream from a `hyper::body::Body` to a file using `tokio::io::AsyncWriteExt` or `tokio::io::{AsyncRead,AsyncWrite}` traits. It seems like in 0.13.5, `hyper::error::Error` cannot be created, so converting from `std::io::Error` to `hyper::error::Error` is impossible in snippets like this:

```
req.into_body().try_fold(file, |file, chunk| async move {
    file.write_all(chunk.as_ref()).await.map(|_| file)
});
```

Is there a simple way to do this?